# Hard drive question about IBM x-series 345

Tags: scsi

We have an IBM x-series 345 that we're looking to upgrade, but I'm having a hard time finding out what the limitations of the hard drive controller are (an Adaptec AIC-7902 RAID controller, supporting U320 SCSI disks). The brochure says the maximum disk capacity of the 345 is 880 gigs, which so happens to be 146.6 x 6. And while there are lots of 146 Gig drives out there, there are also 300 gig drives (or, I suspect they are actually 292 gig drives) available, which would be desirable.

Does the Adaptec 7902 controller just support any drive that happens to be a U320 disk, or is there some kind of size limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put 300GB U320-2 drives into an x345 recently for data recovery purposes. The trick is to have the right drive carrier/sled, some IBM xSeries hot swap disk models will have a blue rubber "tab" that prevents the disk from being inserted into the slot in the server.
Admittedly I was using the ServeRAID 6M card but AFAIK the SCSI card used will make no difference drive size wise.

Comment: Oh yes, we have plenty of spare drive sleds. :)